# Access to a static HTML page using servlet sessions

Tags: java, html, session, servlets

I'm trying to set up access to a static HTML page - lets call it search.html.
I understand I can use cookies for this task, but is it possible with servlet sessions?
What options are there so access is only provided once a user is logged in? I have a login servlet that forwards to search.html however I only want this to be access once a user is logged in and a session is created.

Thanks

Comment: Servlet [`Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in you store something in the Session indicating that. This can be as simple as a boolean flag or a full User object with roles etc. Then you write a filter which checks the presence of this flag or the roles of the user etc. Depending on the outcome you either let the reqest through or deny it with 403 Forbidden. Filters can be configured to paths in the web.xml.